# if statement inside the print statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, printing, boolean, system.out

How can I write an if statement inside the print statement?

```
public boolean checkEmpty()
{
    if(array.isEmpty)
    {
        Sytem.out.println("The List is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The list has: " +  if(array.size() > 1)) {"Items"} + else {"item"} );
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the exact issue, but I take it that you meant to actually print out the number of items, not just "Items" or "Item".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't write an `if` statement inside an expression like that.

However, you can use [Java's ternary operator `?:`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (scroll down about half way in the linked page) to embed a conditional expression:

```
System.out.println("The list has: " +  ((array.size() > 1) ? "items" : "item"));
```

The format is:

```
booleanCondition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

Comment: @mohamedghassar
Don't forget to click on the checkmark if you found this answer to be helpful, though I recognize you cannot do so for another 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

we Do this like

> ***System.out.println(20 > 30 "yes":"no");***
>
> ```
>               ***conditon iftrue : iffalse***
> ```